# Perl Item in Array

Tags: python, arrays, perl, list

I'm new in Perl, which is the easiest way of finding out if the item exists in an array

Like in python I can do this

```
item = 'apple'
list = ['apple', 'banana']
if item in list:
 print item

output >>> 'apple'
```

In perl i can do it in this way

```
my $item = 'appel'
my @array = ('apple', 'banana')
for (@array){
 if ($_ eq $item){ print $item }
}
```

The `for` loop will take too long if my array has more than 100 items

Comment: Depending on how else you are using the contents of the list (and a littany of other considerations), a hash may be the better way to go.  It's search will be O(1) as opposed to the O(n) approach of a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core [`List::Util`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) module provides a convenient alias for looping through all elements until one matches:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(first);

my $item = 'apple';
my @array = ('apple', 'banana');

if (defined first {$_ eq $item} @array) {
    print $item;
}
```

`first` will stop iterating and return the match as soon as it finds one. Unfortunately, since it returns `undef` if no match is found, you can't use it to find if an array contains an `undef` value.

If you have version 1.33 or later you can use the [`any`](http://search.cpan.org/~pevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.39/lib/List/Util.pm#%24b_=_any_%7B_BLOCK_%7D_@list) method which will work for `undef`:

```
use List::Util qw(any);
...
if (any {$_ eq $item} @array) {
    print $item;
}
```

Comment: List::Util's `any` is a better idea. (Though it requires a very recent version of List::Util.) Imagine `my $item = undef` (that is, I'm trying to find out if `undef` is in the array). Your `if` condition will always evaluate to true, whether `@array` contains undef or not!

Comment: Thanks @tobyink, good to see that method added! Updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Note that Python's `in` operator also loops over the list, but does so in optimized C code, so you don't notice the slowness for small to moderate lists. Linear search of large lists *will* take a noticeable amount of time, no matter the language.

Built-in Perl function closest to the `in` operator is the `grep` built-in. `grep {$_ eq $item} @array` in a scalar context will return a true value if `$item` is found inside the array. In your case:

```
my $item = 'apple';
my @array = ('apple', 'banana');
if (grep {$_ eq $item} @array) {
  print $item, "\n";
}
```

Python's `in` operator can also be defined by containers such as `dict` to use container-specific lookup more efficient than linear search. The Perl equivalent of this usage of `in` is the `exists` function.

Answer (score 4):

`any` method from `List::MoreUtils` will return true if any of the elements (stops looking further when first is found) satisfies condition.

```
use List::MoreUtils 'any';

my $item = 'appel';
my @array = ('apple', 'banana');

print "$item\n" if any { $_ eq $item } @array;
```

or using hash slice to make fast lookup,

```
my %look;
@look{@array} = ();
print "$item\n" if exists $look{$item};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out if an item exists in a list of items, then an array is the wrong data structure to use. You should be using a hash.

Of course, it's simple enough to create the hash from an array.

```
my %hash = map { $_ => 1 } @array;

# Then checking for existence is simple
if ($hash{$item}) {
  # do something
}
```

Comment: This is certainly the best way to go if your items are something string-like (e.g. strings, numbers). Otherwise use `any` or `grep`.